# Guys where is the ".yaml" file and ".bat" file present in github repository?

Tags: github, data-science-experience

yaml" file and ".bat" file present in github repository ? I am not able to build a model in anaconda using 'conda build' Can anyone please guide??

> (dl) C:\Users\Nishant>conda build .
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "E:\anaconda\envs\dl\Scripts\conda-build-script.py", line 10, in 
>       sys.exit(main())
>     File "E:\anaconda\envs\dl\lib\site-packages\conda_build\cli\main_build.py", line 469, in main
>       execute(sys.argv[1:])
>     File "E:\anaconda\envs\dl\lib\site-packages\conda_build\cli\main_build.py", line 460, in execute
>       verify=args.verify, variants=args.variants)
>     File "E:\anaconda\envs\dl\lib\site-packages\conda_build\api.py", line 207, in build
>       raise ValueError('No valid recipes found for input: {}'.format(recipe_paths_or_metadata))
>   ValueError: No valid recipes found for input: ['.']

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a minute to  take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)  especially [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) . Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the log, it doesn't mention xxx.yaml or xx.bat file. Probably you are entering wrong input.

.yml file is configuration file called [YAML](https://yaml.org/). While .bat is a kind of Windows execute script. You should read carefully about readme on github repository.